# PGFplots axis label style not working when `axis lines=center` in axis environment options

Tags: pgfplots

When compiling the code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [   
            x label style={rotate=45},
            xlabel=$x$,
            y label style={rotate=45},
            ylabel=$y$,
            z label style={rotate=45,at={(0,0.5)}},
            zlabel=$z$,
            axis lines=center,
            view={45}{20}
        ]
            \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.5] {x^2-y^2};              
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the axis `label style` in the axis environment options do not seem to work.

The resulting picture looks like

[image]

Here you can see that although `rotate=45` is set for each of the labels, they're not in the picture. Also the `at={(0,0.5)}` in `z label style` does not seem to work. But if I remove the command `axis lines=center` everything works fine.

How do I get these options to also work when using `axis lines=center`?

Comment: `axis lines=center` also sets `x label style`, so it overwrites the options you set in `x label style`. Move `axis lines=center` to the start of your options list, and it will work as expected

Comment: @Jake Indeed, works like a charm. Do you want to make an answer out of it or should I do it for you?

Comment: The close vote because this is "unclear" seems misguided given that Jake has answered the question in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like `Jake` states in the comments, `axis lines center` also sets `x label style`, so it overwrites the options you set in `x label style`. Moving `axis lines=center` to the start of the options list solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [   
            axis lines=center, % NOW AT THE TOP INSTEAD OF AT THE BOTTOM OF THE OPTIONS LIST.
            x label style={rotate=45},
            xlabel=$x$,
            y label style={rotate=45},
            ylabel=$y$,
            z label style={rotate=45,at={(0,0.5)}},
            zlabel=$z$,
            view={45}{20}
        ]
            \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.5] {x^2-y^2};              
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]