# plot a elliptic paraboloid graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to plot a 3d graph for function x=y^2 + 4z^2, but it keeps giving me error message, saying float number unreadable, the picture should look like elliptic paraboloid as the picture I attached......here is the code I have (BTW, I totally ripped off the code from [pgfplot: 3d function plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194018/pgfplot-3d-function-plot) Thanks for the brilliant post and answers):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
        X(\y,\z) = \y^2 + 4\z^2;
    }
]
\begin{axis}
[
axis lines=center,
enlargelimits,
tick align=inside,
domain=-1.00:1.00,
samples=20, % this was 200, but I changed it to 20 because of my slow PC
minor tick num=5,
]
\addplot3 [surf] {X(y,z)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `X(\y,\x) = \y^2 + 4\x^2;` and `\addplot3 [surf] {X(y,x)};` instead. Your original declaration `X(\y,\z) = \y^2 + 4\x^2;` does not make too much sense since the left-hand side depends on `\y` and `\z` whereas the right-hand side depends on `\y` and `\x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer to the original question**: The `\x` or `\z` are just place-holders, you could replace them by `\funnylittlefurball` if you wanted. But they need to be consistent on the left and right-hand side of the equation, and there was also a multiplication sign missing. Further, pgfplots expects the variables (i.e. placeholders to be `x` and `y`.

**Answer to the revised question and question in comments**: pgfplots can do two things for you: either plot a function of `x` and `y` or make a parametric plot. Your equation `x=y^2+4z^2` defines for each fixed `x` an ellipse. You can easily confirm that `y=\sqrt{x}\,\cos(t)` and `z=0.5*\sqrt{x}\,\sin(t)` (in LaTeX notation) solve your equation. (**Thanks for pointing this out!**) Now, as pgfplots expects the parameters to be `x` and `y`, I just rename `t` to `y` and arrive at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
        X(\y,\z) = \y^2 + 4*\z^2;
    }
]
\begin{axis}
[view={135}{45},%colormap/blackwhite,
axis lines=center, axis on top,ticks=none,
set layers=default,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
xlabel style={anchor=south east},
ylabel style={anchor=south west},
zlabel style={anchor=south west},
enlargelimits,
tick align=inside,
domain=0:2.00,
samples=20, % this was 200, but I changed it to 20 because of my slow PC
%minor tick num=5,
z buffer=sort,
]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.8,
domain y=-180:0] ({x},{cos(y)*sqrt(x)},{0.5*sin(y)*sqrt(x)});
\addplot3 [surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.8,
domain y=0:180,on layer=axis foreground] ({x},{cos(y)*sqrt(x)},{0.5*sin(y)*sqrt(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center, axis on top,ticks=none,
set layers=default,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
xlabel style={anchor=south west},
ylabel style={anchor=south west},
zlabel style={anchor=south west},
domain=0:2.00,
samples=20,
z buffer=sort,
]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.8,
domain y=-180:0] ({x},{2*cos(y)*sqrt(x)},{sin(y)*sqrt(x)});
\addplot3 [surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.8,
domain y=0:180,on layer=axis foreground] ({x},{2*cos(y)*sqrt(x)},{sin(y)*sqrt(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I adjusted the view to reproduce your picture more closely, made the plot smoother using the `shader=interp` directive (a matter of taste) and perhaps more importantly used the methods of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415498/121799) to achieve better 3D feel. I also inserted  `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` in order to achieve proper placement of the axis labels (and was using the tips of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246010/121799)).

Comment: I need z to be plotted too, it should look like ellipic paraboloid

Comment: @user3390471 What is an elliptic paraboloid? If you provide the defining equation, than people may help you.

Comment: @user3390471 I did providing defining equation

Comment: Can you explain how do you get this: {2*cos(y)*sqrt(x)},{sin(y)*sqrt(x)}??? and the graph should be along x-axis, not y-axis

Comment: @user3390471 I tried to explain what I did in more detail. Could you please tell me if you understand the explanation?

Comment: I still don't get the algebra here......from x= y^2 + 4z^2, I get y=cos(t) \sqrt(x), z=0.5 sin (t) \sqrt(x)........ Substitute your x and y into the equation, I get x=4x.....which is undefined......So I don't get how you get y and z......explain please??? or link me some document so that I can read about it.....

Comment: @user3390471 Very good point! I updated my answer. (I was so focused on explaining how the parametrization arises that I screwed the factor, sorry!)

Answer (score 3):

You are giving `z` as a parameter to the function, but apparently `pgfplots` does not accept this. You should change `X(y,z)` into `X(x,y)`.

Also, you are missing a multiplication sign in your function declaration. It should be:

```
declare function = {%  ↓ Multiplication sign here
    X(\y,\z) = \y^2 + 4*\x^2;
}
```

After that it should work:

[image]

Note, however, that your function's parameters are `\y` and `\z`, but it is computed with `\x` and `\y`. So *I think* it should be:

```
declare function = {%  ↓ Multiplication sign here
    X(\x,\y) = \y^2 + 4*\x^2;
}
```

If I'm wrong, ignore this part of the answer.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
        X(\x,\y) = \y^2 + 4*\x^2;
    }
]
\begin{axis}
[
axis lines=center,
enlargelimits,
tick align=inside,
domain=-1.00:1.00,
samples=20, % this was 200, but I changed it to 20 because of my slow PC
minor tick num=5,
]
\addplot3 [surf] {X(x,y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]